# Rails; display modal after an action and page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the following code...

## controller

```
...
session[:registration_modal] = true
redirect_to(event_path(@event))
```

## _main.html.erb

```
...
<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Registration Notice!</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Thank you for registering for this event. You will not receive $200 and you will not pass go!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->

<% if session[:registration_modal] == true %>
  <%= render :partial => 'registration_modal'%>
  <% session[:registration_modal] = false %>
<% end %>
```

## _registration_modal.html.erb

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">
  $('#registration-modal').modal('show');
</script>
```

This code works. After my controller action runs, I get modal popup. However I would like to move the modal code out of the _main partial and into the _registration_modal partial. But when I do that, the modal is broken. It seems the javascript is looking for `#registration-modal` in _main. How can I tell it to look in _registration_modal?

## Edit

Here is what I would like to make work: https://gist.github.com/marklocklear/24f92405b7e9d1f61de1

Comment: What version of RoR are you using?  Are you using the asset pipeline?  Unless you are including JS directly in your views, I'm not sure why it would matter whether or not you move this to a partial.

Comment: Hey @steveklein This is 3.2.x You are correct, this is purely for code organization. It will not change the behavior any. I will just like the modal view code to 'live' in the _registration_modal partial.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say that it should work whether or not you move the modal code to the partial (which I agree is a good idea).  Can you update your post with a bit about how your JS is organized?

Comment: @steveklein I am using asset pipeline, but in this case have the js in the _registration_modal.html.erb view.

Comment: I would package it in a file and stick it with the rest of your JS (presumably `app/assets/javascripts`), then make sure your manifest file is including it properly.